# How to evaluate which test method is better?

Tags: statistics

The short form of my question is :

Test A shows a useful result after one trial at 16% chance, two trials at 41,7% chance and after three trials with 75% chance. Is it better or worse to use it compared to test B which needs at least two trials and shows a useful result after two trials at 33,3% chance and after three trials with 100% chance. Assuming that you want to use one method until eternity.

Long version:

I have a question to work through my statistics homework (no solution demanded!):

> A company uses a computer with 6 energy regulators. Once in a while
> one of them gets broken. Unfortunately there is no way to figure out
> which is broken, but by testing each one of them.  What is the more
> efficient method to check for long term?
>
> a) test each one after another b) make one isolated test with 3
> (counts as one test) and then test the indicated group of three one by
> another

I would say that this is just a box-experiment : 5 black balls, one white, without putting them back in the box.

in a) you need at least 1 test, but given the worst case, you need 5 tests to find the bad one (either the 5th one is broken or it must be the 6th one).

in b) you need at least 2 tests, but at the worst case 3 tests (isolate the group of three and test 2, if the second wasn't bad it must be the third).

While it is obvious that at 3 tests you find the bad piece at a ratio of 100% with method b), the real question is : How likely is it that in a) you find the bad piece after one and two tests versus how likely is it that you find the bad peace after two tests with method b).

And here I just use formulas for conditional probability from bayes theorem.

That leads me to the following conclusion:

After 2 tests, method a has a 41,7 % chance for success, method b 33,3%. After 3 tests method a has a 75% chance for success, while b has 100% chance.

How do I now evaluate which one of them works better ?

edit: How I got the numbers:
for test b) the chance to get 1 out of the rest of 3 is 33,3%
for test a) I used bayes theorem of conditional probability $p(find_ the broken_ peace|tested_ a_ good_ one_ before) = p(A|B)$ and then you receive the percentages.

Comment: In a) can you show your reasoning for each quoted percentage? In b) how do you 'isolate' the three?

Comment: Oh the isolated test is just given by the exercise : It should mean something like the company has a certain machine which can check 3 at the same time but only can say "all three work" or "not all of them work" - you can not know which one is the bad one, but you can definetly call the group of three which has a bad energy regulator. For the percentages I edit my original post